# In which cases is the copy constructor called, if a container is copied

Tags: c++, stl, constructor

I tested the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
    int m_data;
    foo(int data) : m_data(data) {
        std::cout << "parameterised constructor" << std::endl;
    }
    foo(const foo &other) : m_data(other.m_data) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor" << std::endl;
    }
};

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<foo> a(3, foo(3));
    std::vector<foo> b(4, foo(4));
    //std::vector<foo> b(3, foo(4));
    std::cout << "a = b" << std::endl;
    a = b;
    return 0;
}
```

I get

```
   parameterised constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   parameterised constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   a = b
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
   copy constructor
```

However, if I replace `std::vector<foo> b(4, foo(4));` by `std::vector<foo> b(3, foo(4));` the copy constructor is not called by `a = b` and the output is

```
parameterised constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
parameterised constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
a = b
```

Why is in this case the copy constructor not called?

I'm using g++ (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

Comment: This is really odd... It's even reproducible at ideone...

Comment: Sooo cool. :) I also reproduced that, though I didn't believe it.

Comment: maybe the compiler simply moves b to a since b is not use after the assignment? Have you tried to do something with b after a=b (printing, etc)?

Comment: @user396672 it is not that. I tried it.

Comment: The current standard is C++11, but not everyone is using a C++11 compiler, and the answer might depend on which version of the standard you are targeting so you should make that explicit in the question. Also, just for the sake of it, add the compiler and version, as the implementations of the STL will differ slightly within the bounds of the standard.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the first case, `a` needs to grow when you assign to it, which means that all its elements must be reallocated (and therefore destructed and constructed).

In the second case, `a` does not need to grow, hence the assignment operator is used.

See http://ideone.com/atPt9; adding an overloaded copy assignment operator that prints a message, we get the following for the second example:

```
parameterised constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
parameterised constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
copy constructor
a = b
copy assignment
copy assignment
copy assignment
```

Comment: However, as we know, the `vector` structure reserves some spare elements, in order to assure amortized constant speeds of its operations. Why then copy constructor is used every time nevermind the initial sizes of a and b?

Comment: @Boris: it isn't used nevermind the initial sizes. The whole point of the question is that with one pair of initial sizes it is used, and with another it isn't. Try `std::vector<foo> a(3, foo(3)); std::vector<foo> b(4, foo(4)); a.reserve(4); a = b;`. Assuming Oli's explanation is correct, I think that should copy construct 3 times during the reserve and then copy-construct once during the assignment (and copy-assign three times). If you're on C++11, then normally the `reserve` can move instead of copying, but IIRC a user-defined constructor suppresses the default move constructor.

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: Using the `vector(count, T)` constructor, the capacity is set to `count` (not sure if that's standard-mandated, or implementation-specific).  See e.g. http://ideone.com/jngf9.

Comment: I've tried `std::vector<foo> a(3, foo(3));` `std::vector<foo> b(4, foo(3));`  and `std::vector<foo> c(3, foo(2));` and then `a=b; a=c; a=b;`. In the third case I get 3 assignment and 1 copy calls

Comment: @me after `a=c` the capacity of `a` remains 4, therefore the second `a=b` does not need to allocate new memory and only the last object needs to be (copy) constructed

Answer (score 3):

It is using the assignment operator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
    int m_data;
    foo(int data) : m_data(data) {
        std::cout << "parameterised constructor " << m_data << std::endl;
    }
    foo(const foo &other) : m_data(other.m_data) {
        std::cout << "copy constructor " << m_data << " " << other.m_data << std::endl;
    }

    foo& operator= (const foo& other){
        std::cout << "assignment operator " << m_data << " " << other.m_data << std::endl;
    }
};

main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::vector<foo> a(3, foo(3));
    //std::vector<foo> b(4, foo(4));
    std::vector<foo> b(3, foo(4));
    std::cout << "a = b" << std::endl;
    a = b;

    for(std::vector<foo>::const_iterator it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << "a " << it->m_data << std::endl;
    }
    for(std::vector<foo>::const_iterator it = b.begin(); it != b.end(); ++it){
        std::cout << "b " << it->m_data << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

```
parameterised constructor 3
copy constructor 3 3
copy constructor 3 3
copy constructor 3 3
parameterised constructor 4
copy constructor 4 4
copy constructor 4 4
copy constructor 4 4
a = b
assignment operator 3 4
assignment operator 3 4
assignment operator 3 4
a 3
a 3
a 3
b 4
b 4
b 4
```

See Olis answer for why.